# Revoking password-based login in favour of my Google account

Tags: support

Is there a way to delete my password-based login privilege if I have decided to use my Google account exclusively?

Comment: The password-based login is just another OpenID provider. Add Google to your account, make sure you are logged in with Google, remove the Stack Exchange account.

Comment: Will I lose my user name and question history (and reputation, LOL)?

Comment: Nope, you will not.

Comment: Even if two logins are listed, stackexchange and Google, clicking remove results in `you cannot remove your only account`. So, it seems your suggestion does not work.

Comment: Did you log out from the old account and log back in with the new?

Comment: It's getting more difficult to log out if you don't have the time to hunt for the logout button but I did finally manage to log out.  Yes, I did.....

Comment: All documentation seems to state that that should just work. The help center encourages you to contact the team directly about login issues; the `Contact Us` link at the bottom of every page will get you there. Explain what you did and what didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for a reply. Thanks.